# Validate input field for max value

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

How can I verify that the input field is at maximum 500? Is that possible with a PHP-CI controller?

```
<tr>
       <td>Price</td>
       <td>:</td>
       <td><input name="price"type="text"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Reword text so the question is better to understand

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10">
```

for more details http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/03-maxlength.html

Answer (score 0):

in form: say attribute max, for exaple, html5

```
<input name="price" type="text" min="100" max="500" />
```

in controller (may be ci 3 only)

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'price', 'greater_than_equal_to[100]|less_than_equal_to[500]');
```